# Publish on User's Facebook Wall on behalf of Application Name or Owner (Not as the User itself)

Tags: facebook-wall

I am able to successfully publish/post messages to users' facebook wall from my application (after user authentication/user&app authorization only).

Issue: In the users' facebook wall, the message is posted as if the USER is posting message to   themselves. The title displays the USER NAME and I want to display my APPLICATION NAME. (Note: I can able to see my app name (i.e. "via myappname" at the bottom right of my messages and I need to see this name in the title of the message instead of the user name).

Any help to display my APP NAME on the title of my messages is highly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not possible for pages or apps to write directly onto the Timeline/Profile of users